# Group Similar nodes in XML using XLST

Tags: xml, xslt

I found a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026234/xslt-group-same-nodes-under-parent-as-well-as-in-child-nodes) question to mine, but couldn't figure out a way for my issue.

I have an XML as follows

```
<name>
    <text class="002. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
    <text class="003. DC vs BC">  Sample</text>
    <text class="004. CD vs BC">  Sample</text>
    <text class="005. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
    <text class="006. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
    <text class="007. EF vs BC">  Sample</text>
    <text class="008. CD vs BC">  Sample</text>
    <text class="009. DC vs BC">  Sample</text>
    <text class="010. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
    <text class="011. EF vs BC">  Sample</text>
    <text class="012. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>

</name>
```

And I need to group all the nodes with similar first word in class attribute as follows

```
<name>
    <group name="AB">
        <text class="002. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
        <text class="005. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
        <text class="006. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
        <text class="010. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
        <text class="012. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
    </group>
    <group name="EF">
        <text class="007. EF vs BC">  Sample</text>
        <text class="011. EF vs BC">  Sample</text>
    </group>
    <group name="CD">
        <text class="008. CD vs BC">  Sample</text>
        <text class="004. CD vs BC">  Sample</text>
    </group>
    <group name="DC">
        <text class="003. DC vs BC">  Sample</text>
        <text class="009. DC vs BC">  Sample</text>
    </group>
</name>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: What version of XSLT? If 1.0, you'll need to use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). If > 1.0, you can use [xsl:for-each-group](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#xsl-for-each-group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward grouping problem.

If you're limited to XSLT 1.0, you need to use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

If you're using XSLT 2.0+, you can use [xsl:for-each-group](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#xsl-for-each-group).

Examples...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="class" match="text" 
    use="substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(@class), ' '),' ')"/>

  <!--identity template-->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/name">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="text[count(.|key('class', substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(@class), ' '),' '))[1])=1]">
        <xsl:variable name="key" select="substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(@class), ' '),' ')"/>
        <group name="{$key}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('class',$key)"/>
        </group>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyR

**XSLT 3.0** (you can make this valid 2.0 if you replace the `xsl:mode` with the identity template from the 1.0 stylesheet)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="text" 
        group-by="tokenize(normalize-space(@class),'\s+')[2]">
        <group name="{current-grouping-key()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyR/1

Note: The output does not have the same order as your example, but I didn't see any logic to the ordering.

Comment: I have updated the XML code in the post above. Can you please provide me an XSL 1.0 solution? I couldn't figure it out

Comment: @Gangula - After you updated your question, you made my answer and the other answer obsolete. I'm going to roll back the revision. Here is an updated fiddle to try to handle the new requirements: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyR/16 If that doesn't help, please create a new question.

Comment: Sorry, @Daniel, I have updated the question and waited for few days, but I think since it was marked solved, it didn't receive any attention. Thank you for the update. Really helpful

Comment: Can you please suggest a resource for me to learn XSL. I would like to make few similar codes for few of my other XML files.

Comment: @Gangula - Michael Kay's "XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0" book would be a good resource, even for XSLT 1.0. I know Dimitre Novatchev has a course on Pluralsight. I haven't used it, but Dimitre definitely knows his stuff. Links can be found at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info (along with a link to G. Ken Holman's book)

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT-2.0 you can use `xsl:for-each-group` with these templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="text" group-by="tokenize(@class,' ')[2]">
            <group name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
<name>
   <group name="AB">
      <text class="002. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
      <text class="005. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
      <text class="006. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
      <text class="010. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
      <text class="012. AB vs BC">  Sample</text>
   </group>
   <group name="DC">
      <text class="003. DC vs BC">  Sample</text>
      <text class="009. DC vs BC">  Sample</text>
   </group>
   <group name="CD">
      <text class="004. CD vs BC">  Sample</text>
      <text class="008. CD vs BC">  Sample</text>
   </group>
   <group name="EF">
      <text class="007. EF vs BC">  Sample</text>
      <text class="011. EF vs BC">  Sample</text>
   </group>
</name>
```